# Изменить type кнопки Javascript

Tags: javascript

Нужно через js изменить `type` у `button`

```
document.querySelector("button.someClass") ...?
```

Как это сделать?

Кнопка

```
<button type="submit" class="someClass">Click here</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

используя [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) находим элемент [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/DOM)

```
const el = document.querySelector('button.someClass');
```

и используя [element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) производим замену атрибута `type`:

```
el.setAttribute('type', 'reset');
```

```js
const el = document.querySelector('button.someClass');
console.log('before -> ', el);
el.setAttribute('type', 'reset');
console.log('after -> ', el)
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="someClass">Click here</button>
```